# getting Cannot specify both an external ID reference Owner and a salesforce id, OwnerId while upserting account using dataloader

Tags: data-loader

We are getting 'Cannot specify both an external ID reference Owner and a salesforce id, OwnerId' error while upserting account record. Any idea?

Comment: Remove one or the other from the imported file. What is it specifically that you are having trouble with?

Comment: If possible please add a screenshot of your csv file, with the relevant columns only. Most probably you are specifying Owner & OwnerId both in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is as simple as the error message is giving you. You cannot specify an External ID field *and* the Salesforce ID in Updates or Upserts from Dataloader - because imagine if in your data the **Salesforce ID** referenced one record, but the **External ID** actually was on a different record; which one would it upsert? It would have no choice but to blow up.